# Angular 4 Animate list item by item

Tags: angular, angular-animations

I wish to animate a list `ul > li` item by item.

It's OK when query `:enter`, but I need to animate the `:leave` state **before** the `:enter` when list elements change, how can I do that?

Follow my actual code:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'ng-list',
  templateUrl: './ng-list.component.html',
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  animations: [

    trigger('listAnimation', [
      transition('* => *', [

        query(':enter', style({ opacity: 0 }), { optional: true }),

        query(':enter', stagger('300ms', [
          animate('1s ease-in', keyframes([
            style({ opacity: 0, transform: 'translateY(-75%)', offset: 0 }),
            style({ opacity: .5, transform: 'translateY(35px)', offset: 0.3 }),
            style({ opacity: 1, transform: 'translateY(0)', offset: 1.0 }),
          ]))]), { optional: true })

      ])
    ])

  ]
})
export class NgListComponent {

  items: Array<any>;
  animateItems = false;

  constructor() {
    this.items = new Array<INgxSidemenuItem>();
  }

  selectMenu(item: INgxSidemenuItem) {
    this.animate();

    // ...
  }

  private animate() {
    this.animateItems = !this.animateItems;
  }

}
```

```html
<div [@listAnimation]="animateItems">
  <div class="menu-item" *ngFor="let item of items (click)="selectMenu(item)">
    <a (click)="selectMenu(item)">{{ item.title }}</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not supposed to query `':enter'`. `:enter` is just a shorthand for `void => *` meaning it can be used in a `transition()` to declare between what states the transition regards. What you want is to query a selector. Since `query()` uses `document.querySelectorAll()` behind the scenes, you can use any CSS selector to get select the elements that you want to stagger. What you therefore want to do is to query the divs, either by just the tag or by the class name. For example, using the class name:

```
trigger('listAnimation', [
  transition('* => *', [

    query('.menu-item', style({ opacity: 0 }), { optional: true }),

    query('.menu-item', stagger('300ms', [
      animate('1s ease-in', keyframes([
        style({ opacity: 0, transform: 'translateY(-75%)', offset: 0 }),
        style({ opacity: .5, transform: 'translateY(35px)', offset: 0.3 }),
        style({ opacity: 1, transform: 'translateY(0)', offset: 1.0 }),
      ]))]), { optional: true })

  ])
])
```

Comment: As far as I understand the question was how to animate the "old" element leaving and the new element entering